# How to combine URL params and body POST params when saving object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `parent_id` appended to the URL of a form page (when it is linked from an existing '`block`' page in my app)

I then have inputs of that form submitted when creating a new `block` (which should create a `'child block'` with the `parent_id` contained in the URL)

But when I try save with this :

```
def create
    @block = Block.new(block_params)

    if @block.save
      redirect_to @block
    else 
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

with `block_params` as :

```
private 
    def block_params
      params.require(:block).permit(:title, :body, :parent_id)
    end
```

It only saves the `:title` and `:body` params and ignores the `:parent_id` in the URL.

If I try and manually combine them e.g.

```
def create
        @block = Block.new(block_params, parent_id: [parent_id)
```

I get the error of `'params should be between 0...1'` (which makes sense)

What am I missing on why this isn't saving the URL param as well?

**EDIT**

Model detail is here

```
class Block < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Block', foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Block', foreign_key: :parent_id
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

Comment: What do your parameters look like?

Comment: What does your model look like? `parent_id` may not match the expected parameter

Comment: sorry what do you mean? The block params code is above. The title is a string, body also a string, the parent_id is an integer in the URL in this format  http://localhost:3000/blocks/new?parent_id=6

Comment: added model above

Comment: I mean what do the params being passed to your create method look like. ie a post with parameters: `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "organization"=>{"name"=>"Chase Inc", "website"=>"", "description"=>""} }` as an example from one of my projects

Comment: on the show page it is #<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"blocks", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"7"} permitted: false>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249204/discussion-between-chase-mcdougall-and-nc14).

Comment: I posted a merge option as an answer but it's functionality is dependent on what parameters are being passed to your `create` method. Assuming the parent_id is being sent alongside the new parameters it should work, otherwise you may need too pass the parent_id as a hidden parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be combined using the [parameter merge method](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionController/Parameters/merge)

ie `@block = Block.new(block_params.merge(parent_id: params[:parent_id))`

Comment: Okay thanks - I will try it - I didn’t think you needed to do this because rails was “agnostic” to where params came from but will try!